# Can I pass Android styles in parameters with Xamarin.Forms XAML

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way (without using a renderer) that I can set styling for Android switches in a way like this:

```
<Switch android:colorControlActivated="#FF00FF" 
 HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center" 
 IsToggled="{Binding PbSwitch}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is shared logic, you can't use platform spec staff there without abstraction. Why does renderer not suit you?

Comment: I would be okay with the renderer but there's an issue with that right now.  I opened up another SO question trying to get some help on that issue which stops the renderer from working with latest version of Android.